# need to convert a mathematical string to its calculated value

Tags: mysql, sql

i have query like

```
SELECT equation FROM eqs;
```

and results are

```
[equation]
[  1x1   ]
[  2x2   ]
[  3x3   ]
[  4x4   ]
[  5x5   ]
[  6x6   ]
```

how to make it instead calculate the string as an equation and give me results of it in form of

```
[equation]
[   1    ]
[   4    ]
[   9    ]
[   16   ]
[   25   ]
[   36   ]
```

Comment: Use dynamic SQL (prepared statement).

Comment: Purely done in SQL?

Comment: @Cid yes to be used for sorting or calculation outside of its string

Comment: we'd need to use a function that evalutes the equation string. im not aware of any builtin function that would do that, so we would have to roll our own.    we could name the function `evaluate_equation` ,    query would be of the form,  `SELECT  q.equation, evaluate_equation(q.equation) FROM eqs q ORDER BY q.equation`  (returning both the original string, and the result returned from the function.)